# Mainframe FTP login with userID without password

Tags: ftp, mainframe

I am using apache ftpclient for using ftp with mainframe.
I am able to connect, logon & retrieve file using my userid & password.

However for a implementation pointof view, **I have a userid without password**.
How I can use this userid with the apache ftpclient without giving password ?
Note: I tried as anonymous as well. However it fails as there is no password.

ftp.login( "anonymous", "" );

Thanks in advance,
rinku

Comment: Please note that by "I have a userid without password" I mean the userid is with no password i.e. I can logon without giving password.

Comment: The anonymous user often accepts any password at all.. try `guest` or `a@hp.com` which is short !

Comment: I tried but no success.Thanks Mark.

Comment: I don't know the Apache client, but can you send "USER" command like this "USER anonymous" rather than calling `login`?